# Triple meta_key on custom SELECT query

Tags: post-meta, mysql, wpdb, select

I'm using a weird SELECT query to calculate the average of all the post ratings (stored in `wp_postmeta`) for a certain user.

My query basically uses the following arguments:

> `post_author = 1` AND `meta_key = 'rating'` AND `meta_value != 0`.

This query works perfectly fine on it's own, but here's where it gets complicated. I need to add some exceptions...

> `meta_key = 'anonymous'` AND `meta_value != 'true'`

And another...

> `meta_key = 'original_author'` AND `meta_value = ''`

I want to retrieve only the `rating` meta_values, so I'll probably run into more problems using `$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value`.

This totals up to 3 `meta_key` and `meta_value` arguments, with only one `meta_value` that I actually want to retrieve. It just gets more and more tricky...

See my code below:

```
// Example value
    $user_id = 1;

// Calculate average post rating for user
    $ratings_query = $wpdb->get_results(
                        $wpdb->prepare("
                            SELECT $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value 
                            FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                                JOIN $wpdb->posts ON ($wpdb->postmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id)
                                    WHERE ( 
                                        $wpdb->posts.post_author = %d AND 
                                        $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND 
                                        $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
                                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'rating' AND 
                                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value != 0

                                        AND

                                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'anonymous' AND 
                                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value != 'true'

                                        AND

                                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'original_author' AND 
                                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = '')
                        ", $user_id), ARRAY_N);

    if ( $ratings_query ) {
        $ratings_query = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $ratings_query);       
        $average_rating = round(array_sum($ratings_query) / count($ratings_query), 1);
    } else {
        $average_rating = 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here. If there's a problem with the code snippet, please explain that in more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Query is incorrect. To retrive meta values for triple meta_key you will need 3 different joins using posts meta on posts table.
Check code below:

```
// Example value
$user_id = 1;

// Calculate average post rating for user
$ratings_query = $wpdb->get_results(
                     $wpdb->prepare("
SELECT pmeta.meta_value  
    FROM wp_posts
      LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pmeta 
        ON (pmeta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id) 
      LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pmeta1 
        ON (pmeta1.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id) 
      LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pmeta2 
        ON (pmeta2.post_id = $wpdb->posts.id) 
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_author = %d AND 
    $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' AND 
    $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
      AND (
        pmeta.meta_key = 'rating' 
        AND CAST(pmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) != '0'
      ) 
      AND (
        pmeta1.meta_key = 'anonymous' 
        AND CAST(pmeta1.meta_value AS CHAR) != 'true'
      ) 
      AND (
        pmeta2.meta_key = 'original_author' 
        AND CAST(pmeta2.meta_value AS CHAR) = ''
      )", $user_id), ARRAY_N);
```

To retrive meta data using custom query, you will need 1 joins for each meta data pairs on posts table as above.

if you print last SQL query using code `echo $wpdb->last_query;` , you will get SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  pmeta.meta_value 
FROM
  wp_posts 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pmeta 
    ON (pmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id) 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pmeta1 
    ON (pmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.id) 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pmeta2 
    ON (pmeta2.post_id = wp_posts.id) 
WHERE wp_posts.post_author = 1 
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND (
    pmeta.meta_key = 'rating' 
    AND CAST(pmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) != '0'
  ) 
  AND (
    pmeta1.meta_key = 'anonymous' 
    AND CAST(pmeta1.meta_value AS CHAR) != 'true'
  ) 
  AND (
    pmeta2.meta_key = 'original_author' 
    AND CAST(pmeta2.meta_value AS CHAR) = ''
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the other answer but I thought I'd add this as a different method as it's simple and uses WP to work out the SQL Query. It would be slightly heavier on resources as there are extra queries with the `get_post_meta` function.

```
$user_id = 1;
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'orderby' => 'date',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'meta_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                          'key' => 'post_author',
                                          'value' => $user_id
                                          ),
                                    array(
                                          'key' => 'rating',
                                          'compare' => '!=', // or'>'
                                          'value' => 0
                                          ),
                                    array(
                                          'key' => 'anonymous',
                                          'compare' => '!=',
                                          'value' => true
                                          ),
                                    array(
                                          'key' => 'original_author',
                                          'compare' => '!=',
                                          'value' => ''
                                          )
                                    )
              );

$RelevantPosts = get_posts($args);

$ratings = array();
foreach($RelevantPosts as $RelevantPost) {
    $ratings[] = get_post_meta($RelevantPost->ID, 'rating' , true);
}

if ( $RelevantPosts ) {
    $average_rating = round(array_sum($ratings) / count($ratings), 1);
} else {
    $average_rating = 0;
}
```

It is however simple to read and understand and so long as it not run in mass (eg for all your posts at once) it should be fine for resources.

Comment: This works, but it does not answer the question as the question uses `$wpdb` and this solution does not.

Comment: The solution does use `$wpdb`... It uses `get_posts()` which uses `WP_Query` and if you do happen to read `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php` and watch what happens there... you'll see it use `$wpdb` if that matters a lot to you.